# What is the sequence of preprocessing operations when using Keras ImageDataGenerator?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

When You use `ImageDataGenerator`, there are lots of preprocessing functions given and we can pass our own preprocessing input too. Let us suppose we use `MobileNet` as a pre-trained model and we'll use the corresponding `preprocesss_input` function. Let us suppose we `init` the class as below:

```
tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=True,featurewise_std_normalization=True,zca_whitening=True, 
    rotation_range=13, width_shift_range=0.13,height_shift_range=0.2, shear_range=0.06, zoom_range=0.1,
    horizontal_flip=True, vertical_flip=True, 
    rescale=1./255.,preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)
```

What will be the sequence of transformations here? Whether the rescaling will happen first or the `preprocess_function` or such. If we use `ZCA`, the covariance shift will result in range change and then there will be no meaning of using `rescale`. Same will happen with `std_norm`. Also, if we use `preprocess_function`, different models use different such as `-1 to 1` or `0-1` range so the rescale won't be affective. Different sequence combinations will lead in different statistics for the image.

For the other transformations like zoom, crop, rotation etc,

1. Will these happen all at once? OR the class will select one transformation at a time?
2. If it is selecting all at once, zooming -> flipping -> Shifting -> rotating -> shearing will lead to an alien object in the image. Where doing one or more in random order makes sense for the cases.

Can someone please shed some light on the inner workings of the order of the functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Whether the rescaling will happen first or the preprocess_function or
> such

Rescaling will be applied after the transformations are done. `preprocess_function` after augmention.

For `featurewise` functionalities, you need to fit the generator to the data. From the [docs](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/#imagedatagenerator-class):

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=True,
    featurewise_std_normalization=True,
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)
# compute quantities required for featurewise normalization
# (std, mean, and principal components if ZCA whitening is applied)
datagen.fit(x_train)
```

> Will these happen all at once? OR the class will select one
> transformation at a time?

Transformations are applied **randomly** on **each image**. `preprocess_function` will be applied on **each image** after the augmention completed.

> If it is selecting all at once, zooming -> flipping -> Shifting ->
> rotating -> shearing will lead to an alien object in the image. Where
> doing one or more in random order makes sense for the cases.

Exactly, they will seem awkard. But you specify **ranges** when using ImageDataGenerator. So transformations will be applied in that range, randomly.

**Example:**

```
generator = ImageDataGenerator(
    zoom_range=0.9, horizontal_flip=True, vertical_flip=True, rotation_range=13, width_shift_range=0.13,height_shift_range=0.2, shear_range=0.6, 
    )
```

**Will generate:**

[image]

It is clear that not every image is zoomed with a factor of **0.9** or vice versa.

Comment: I checked the `standardize` function of `DataGenerator` class and this what I got: `preprocessing_function -> rescale -> samplewise_center -> samplewise_std_normalization -> 
  -> featurewise_center -> featurewise_std_normalization -> zca_whitening ` where `zca` overrides `featurewise_std_normalization` setting it to `False`.

Comment: The question here is that `MobileNet` wants the images to be in `[-1,1]` range but the rescaling `1/255` will shift it to numbers very close to 0 and again, if any normalization is done, it'll change defeat the purpose of `preprocess_function`. How can that be prevented?

Comment: If you want them to be in range [-1,1] just rescale with *1/127.5 - 1*. I don't see your point why you want to use them all. Rescaling with *1/127.5 - 1* should be fine.

Comment: Oh okay. My bad. I just. I just calculated that `1/127.5-1`. It'll keep the values in same `[-1,1]` range. So in simple terms, if we use `preprocess_input()` we don't even have to bother using `rescale`. Also, if we `standardize` the values say `X-mean/std`, it'll again change the range right? what about that?

Comment: Or you mean to ay that if we use `preprocess_input` regarding to pre trained model, we shouldn't bother using `normalizing` or `standardizing` them `sample` or `featurewise`?

Comment: AFAIK, `preprocess_input` should be fine itself. But `preprocess_input` will do it in a sample-wise manner. For feature-wise and sample-wise you may want to check that: [should-i-normalize-featurewise-or-samplewise](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/354774/should-i-normalize-featurewise-or-samplewise)